# Is there a way to combine my cookied StackOverflow login with my new openId one

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, login, merge-accounts

I posted and answered a question as a cookied user . Then I logged in using openId. I have now lost the connection to my original questions and answers (and badge). Is there a way to combine these for the user bucho.

Answer (score 2):

email team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: "we" (♦) can do this too...

Comment: I didn't know we could merge unknown users with regular users.

Comment: user page => mod => Merge

Answer (score 2):

For info all: posting here on "meta" works too. And has better around-the-clock coverage.

(Identity confirmed via non-public data)

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to team@stackoverflow.com explaining the situation.

If you can, edit the duplicate, and write in the description that it is a dup of your other account. You may also want to edit the description of the original, if you can. This will help prove that the person who owns the duplicate account, is in fact the same person who owns the other account.

I have actually done this, and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: You probably don't need to go through all the trouble to "prove" you own the other account when all they have to do is check the IPs

Comment: Probably not, but there isn't a problem of giving them too much data.